# Why doesn't my galaxy s4 screen display anything?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, screen, stock-android

My Samsung galaxy s4 will suddenly not show anything on the display anymore. It vibrates and such as if everything but the display works. Sometimes it will flash something that looks a bit like part of the android guy, but it flashes so fast I cannot be sure that is what is it or if it just flashes.

I have tried the top solutions that my google search have led me to try:

-Removing the battery and holding volume up and home button for ten seconds.
-Removing the battery and holding the power button for a minute and letting the phone sit for 5 minutes.

It is possible that the phone received a hit during the day that led to this problem but other people who have had this problem have not had it because of any hit or drop and I am therefore not 100% sure that any hit it may have received during the day caused this problem or if it is software related.

**My question:**
Why doesn't my galaxy s4 screen display anything and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the battery and pulling it back in again. Then hold power button + home + volume up for a few seconds until the screen lights up. If nothing shows up the screen make sure your battery if loaded. Try it again and if that doesn't work either. Try exactly the same except you use the volume down now and not the volume up. If that doesn't work it's probably a hardware problem. It's not software because the last update was a few months ago so then it would've been occurred earlier.

It could be a software problem if you've rooted your phone. Try flashing your stock software on it. You can't see anything but moving through download mode isn't that hard. Power + home + volume down. Wait a few secs, press volume up. Plug into PC using USB and flash stock software using Odin. If it isn't rooted it's a hardware problem. Go to your nearest Samsung Repair Center and maybe the repair is free because of the warranty. Unless it's rooted of course.

Comment: +0. Thank you for answering. But: Please split your answer into paragraphs, in order to make it more readable, and copyedit it in order to eliminate all "autocomplete" typos. :) And maybe add **bold headings**.

Comment: @LucasVL7 This did not solve my problem but it might be helpful to others and I have therefore marked your answer as correct. Thank-you for your help.

Comment: @user73759 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Backlight is gone,  I have the same problem, I had to send it back (luckily I have insurance) now it has happened again, I can't be asked to send it back and go for another 2 weeks without a phone so I have been searching the web for solutions but I can't find any. However your problem is the backlight of your phone.

Comment: Do you have a link to any resources that back up this diagnosis? Others with the same problem and solution?

Answer (score -1):

None of these theories work. You really need to go and see a Samsung repair specialist, and hopefully, you won't have to pay anything for it if it's under warranty or if it's insured. If they can't fix it your screed and will have to get a new phone x

Comment: Anger or emotions doesn't help! Only well-written, structured, and reasoned answers help. If you find any answer unhelpful, then simply downvote it, comment the fault, or post your answer in a *civil* manner. Anyhow!